# Construct SQL where clause to pull data within Power Query

Tags: t-sql, powerquery

Basically I want to retrieve rows of data that meet my clause conditions using Power Query.

I got 400 rows of lookup values in my spreadsheet.
Each row represent 1 lookup code for example, code AAA1, AAB2 and so on

So lets say I have a select statement and I want to construct the where clauses using the above codes so my end sql statement will look like

```
select * from MyTable where Conditions in ('AA1', 'AAB2')
```

so so far I have this

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Form ID",    
Int64.Type}}),
test = Sql.Database("myserver", "myDB", [Query="SELECT * FROM  myTable where" & #"Changed Type" & "])"
```

in
 test

Obviously that didnt work but thats my pseduo scenario anyway.

Please could you advice what to do?
Thank you
Peddie

Comment: Well what happened? Did it run but no data? Error out?

Comment: actually instead of "where" it should be "in" but even that, it throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a "lookup" Power Query based on the Excel table. I would set the "Load To" properties to "Only Create Connection".

Then I would start the main Query by connecting to the SQL server using the Navigator to select "MyTable".  Then I would add a Merge step to the main Query, to join to the "lookup" Query, matching the "Conditions" column to the "lookup" code.  I would set the Join Type to "Inner".  The Merge properties window will show you visually if the 2 columns you select actually contain matching data.

This approach does not require any coding, and is easier to build, extend and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Honey's join is best for your problem, but here's a more general solution if you find yourself needing other logic in your where clause.

---

Normally Power query only generates row filters on an equality expression, but you can put any code you want in a `Table.SelectRows` filter, like `each List.Contains({"AA1", "AAB2"}, [Conditions])`

So for your table, your query would look something like:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Form ID", Int64.Type}}),
    test = Sql.Database("myserver", "myDB"),
    yourTable = test{[Name="myTable"]}[Data],
    filtered = Table.SelectRows(yourTable, each List.Contains(#"Changed Type"[Form ID], [Conditions]))
in
    filtered
```

The main downside to using the library functions is that `Table.SelectRows` only knows how to generate SQL where clauses for specific expression patterns, so the row filter probably runs on your machine after downloading the whole table, instead of having the Sql Server run the filter.